# Testing Observable with subscribe in a function

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs, angular5, rxjs6

Here is the testbed setup. Mocking and providing everything needed:

```
 let component: PageUploadContainer;
  let store;
  let route;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PageUploadContainer>;
  const sanitizer = jasmine.createSpyObj('sanitizer', ['bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl']);
  sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl.and.callFake(url => url);
  const mockTranslate = {
    instant: label => label,
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = createMockStore<AppState>(reducers);
    route = new MockActivatedRoute();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [translationModule],
      declarations: [
        PageUploadContainer,
        MockTranslatePipe,
        MockTranslateCutPipe,
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        FormBuilder,
        { provide: DomSanitizer, useValue: sanitizer },
        { provide: Store, useValue: store },
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: route },
        { provide: TranslateService, useFactory: () => mockTranslate },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PageUploadContainer);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.mappingTriggered$ = Observable.of(false);
  });
```

I have the following code, I set up me tests with testBed:

```
onGoTo(uploadStep: string) {
    if (uploadStep === NAVIGATION.DEFAULT) {
      this.store.dispatch(new ReplaceSelectedCompanies([]));
      this.companyIds$.filter(isEmpty)
        .take(1)
        .subscribe(() => {
          this.store.dispatch(new Navigate({ direction: uploadStep}));
        });
    } else {
      this.store.dispatch(new Navigate({ direction: uploadStep}));
    }
  }
```

And my test. This test fails due to `new Navigate({ direction: uploadStep})` was not called due to it's asynchronous nature

```
it('if navigation default and companyIds empty should call navigate', () => {
       component.companyIds$ = Observable.of(['123', '234']);
      component.onGoTo(NAVIGATION.DEFAULT);
      expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new ReplaceSelectedCompanies([]));
      expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new Navigate({ direction: NAVIGATION.DEFAULT }));
    });
```

Can you help me how to test such methods?

Comment: Please post your setup. I don’t see the testbed. Also, it is asynchronous but your test is running synchronously.

Comment: @christo8989 added a setup

Answer (score 2):

Although I am not certain, you might need to just import the `async` method provided by angular.

**General Example**

```
it("description", async( /* function */ ));
```

**Your Code**

```
import { async } from "@angular/core/testing";

it('if navigation default and companyIds empty should call navigate', async(() => {
  component.companyIds$ = Observable.of(['123', '234']);
  component.onGoTo(NAVIGATION.DEFAULT);
  expect(store.dispatch)
    .toHaveBeenCalledWith(new ReplaceSelectedCompanies([]));
  expect(store.dispatch)
    .toHaveBeenCalledWith(new Navigate({ direction: NAVIGATION.DEFAULT }));
}));
```

**Recommendations**

First, I would [watch this video about angular 6 asynchronous unit tests](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/asynchronous/). The whole unit test series is good too.

You have a lot of custom-ly mocked classes so I can't comment much on that. I do recommend using `RouterTestingModule.withRoutes({ /* test routes */ })`. [Here's another video in that series that talks about the RouterTestingModule](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/routing/).

Then, you could always get the mocked router like `router = TestBed.get(Router)` or other objects created by the `RouterTestingModule`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create asynchronous Jasmine tests by calling `done()` after your tested code has executed completely. You get the `done` function passed as an argument from the test spec, like that:

```
it('if navigation default and companyIds empty should call navigate', (done) => {
   ...
});
```

However, you wouldn't know in your test code when the code has executed completely. I'd suggest returning a Promise from `onGoTo. It could look like that:

```
onGoTo(uploadStep: string): Promise<void> {
    if (uploadStep === NAVIGATION.DEFAULT) {
      this.store.dispatch(new ReplaceSelectedCompanies([]));
      return new Promise(resolve => this.companyIds$.filter(isEmpty)
        .take(1)
        .subscribe(() => {
          this.store.dispatch(new Navigate({ direction: uploadStep}));
          resolve();
        }));
    } else {
      this.store.dispatch(new Navigate({ direction: uploadStep}));
      return Promise.resolve();
    }
  }
```

Then, modify your test code like that:

```
it('if navigation default and companyIds empty should call navigate', (done) => {
   component.companyIds$ = Observable.of(['123', '234']);
  component.onGoTo(NAVIGATION.DEFAULT).then(() => {
    expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new ReplaceSelectedCompanies([]));
    expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new Navigate({ direction: NAVIGATION.DEFAULT }));
    done()});
});
```